# AndEngine - 'Cannot resolve symbol' error in Vector2 class

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine, game-development

I started developing an android game using an AndEngine version of [RealMayo](https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEngine) and after going through several tutorials, I was able to configure my android studio to develop a game.

Following is how I added AndEngine and AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension as modules to my project.

[image: Project structure]

And, dependencies were added as told in [this](http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/) blog.

**In app `build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':andEngine')
    compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension')
}
```

**In andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension `build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':andEngine')
}
```

**There are no dependencies in andEngine `build.gradle` file**

Problem is when I started to clean or run project in a device, following error prompted in messages window.

[image: Error in messages window]

After clicking the highlighted error, IDE navigated to Vector2 class which is in andEngine module, and showed following error.

[image]

First thing I tried was, adding dependency of andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension module in andEngine, since some classes in andEngine module depend on classes in andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension module, like Vector2. Here's how I add dependencies in andEngine module.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension')
}
```

But then, I got following error in messages window.

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this problem. I hope my question is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out my existing AndEngine projects and found no such class `org.andengine.entity.primitive.Vector2`

First of all, module `andEngine` is not depended on any other modules, so remove

```
compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension')
```

from `andEngine.gradle` file.

And then delete that `Vector2.java` file.

**Note:** I'm using the latest [AndEngine branch (GLES2.0 AC)](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter). You might want to replace your current AndEngine codes with codes provided by this branch.

Comment: I replaced the andEngine version of [ReayMayo](https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEngine) with orginal andEngine by [Nicolas Gramlich](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) and it worked! As you said, there is  no such class named Vector2 in Nicolas Gramlich's andEngine but, in RealMayo's version.